# How to install Windows XP on acer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive

I have an Acer laptop core i3. When I try to install Windows XP on my computer, the installation does not complete and a blue screen is displayed with the follwing statement:

> Check for viruses on your computer. Remove any newly installed hard drive or harddrive controllers. Check your hard drive to make sure it is properly configured and terminated. Run CHKDSK/F to check for hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer.
>   Technical Information:

Comment: eh, Why're you trying to install a 12 year old OS? You might be having issues with hardware that was never supported on windows.

Comment: It would have been really nice to actually get the relevant "Technical information" that was cut off in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can mean your hard drive is damaged or got bad sector. Check/scan your hard drive first

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion would be to rather try a different copy of XP. Although there is a chance for the hard drive to be faulty, I think it has got to do with the installation copy instead.